# Facebook crawler with no user agent spamming our site in possible DoS attack

Tags: web-crawlers, facebook, cdn, cloudflare, ddos

Crawlers registered to Facebook (ipv6 ending in :face:b00c::1) were slamming our site, seeing 10s of thousands of hits in just 20 minutes. We noticed they didn't have a user agent in the header and implemented a rule on cloudflare to protect ourselves.

It appears they've patched the crawler and added a user agent 'Externalhit/1.1' which is a recognised crawler. Now they're circumventing the rule, I'm seeing 11,000 hits in 15 minutes. Often multiple times to the same page! This is crippling our database. It's prevent customers from legitimately using the site.

We've implemented a broad block on all of Facebook's IPs in order to try and remedy this but we've likely already lost business because of it.

My question is: Has anyone seen this before? Any idea what's causing it? Is there a channel for getting a response from Facebook or is there a legal route we should go?

Link to our tweet: https://twitter.com/TicketSource/status/969148062290599937
Tried FB developers group, and Facebook rep and were directed to Support. Filed a ticket, no response.

Log sample:

```
2018-03-01 09:00:33 10.0.1.175 GET /dylanthomas - 443 - facebookexternalhit/1.1 - 200 0 0 5394 2a03:2880:30:7fcf:face:b00c:0:8000
2018-03-01 09:00:33 10.0.1.175 GET /dylanthomas - 443 - facebookexternalhit/1.1 - 200 0 0 5362 2a03:2880:30:afd1:face:b00c:0:8000
2018-03-01 09:00:33 10.0.1.175 GET /dylanthomas - 443 - facebookexternalhit/1.1 - 200 0 0 5378 2a03:2880:30:7fcf:face:b00c:0:8000
2018-03-01 09:00:33 10.0.1.175 GET /dylanthomas - 443 - facebookexternalhit/1.1 - 200 0 0 5425 2a03:2880:30:2fea:face:b00c:0:8000
2018-03-01 09:00:33 10.0.1.175 GET /dylanthomas - 443 - facebookexternalhit/1.1 - 200 0 0 5394 2a03:2880:30:2fea:face:b00c:0:8000
2018-03-01 09:00:33 10.0.1.175 GET /dylanthomas - 443 - facebookexternalhit/1.1 - 200 0 0 5659 2a03:2880:30:2fd8:face:b00c:0:8000
2018-03-01 09:00:33 10.0.1.175 GET /dylanthomas - 443 - facebookexternalhit/1.1 - 200 0 0 5659 2a03:2880:11:dff3:face:b00c:0:8000
2018-03-01 09:00:36 10.0.1.175 GET /whitedreamspremiere - 443 - facebookexternalhit/1.1 - 200 0 0 5048 2a03:2880:2020:bffb:face:b00c:0:8000
2018-03-01 09:00:36 10.0.1.175 GET /helioscollective - 443 - facebookexternalhit/1.1 - 200 0 0 4633 2a03:2880:3020:1ffd:face:b00c:0:8000
2018-03-01 09:00:36 10.0.1.175 GET /helioscollective - 443 - facebookexternalhit/1.1 - 200 0 0 4727 2a03:2880:3011:afc5:face:b00c:0:8000
2018-03-01 09:00:36 10.0.1.175 GET /helioscollective - 443 - facebookexternalhit/1.1 - 200 0 0 4977 2a03:2880:3020:1ffd:face:b00c:0:8000
2018-03-01 09:00:36 10.0.1.175 GET /event/FDMEJD - 443 - facebookexternalhit/1.1 - 200 0 0 4868 2a03:2880:2111:1ff9:face:b00c:0:8000
```

Edit2: These IPs are crawling as we've found URLs from our payment process. So they followed a link and ended up in a session only URL.

Edit3: Facebook appear to have [confirmed the bug and are looking for a fix](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1894024420610804).

Comment: Just want to update that this is ongoing and a devastating DDOS attack in effect. We're getting over 1000 hits per second to unique URLs that are impossible to keep cached. Even when we rate-limit them (499 response codes) they keep hammering us. Another report URL: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1259828030848113/

Comment: Worth noting: I no longer see the no-UA hits, now the ones I get are always `facebookexternalhit` at least, from a wide range of IPs that trace back to FB.

Comment: This is actually being leveraged in DDOS attacks now https://thehackernews.com/2014/04/vulnerability-allows-anyone-to-ddos.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1894024420610804

Per the answer from Facebook, any page shared on Facebook should expect that if their content is shared Facebook crawlers will increase traffic 10-20x that number of shares.

This sounds like Facebook is scraping the content every single time it's accessed, with little to no caching in place.

In our case, while Facebook is probably good for advertising overall, this is an immense strain when you run a database intensive page that's shared. We'll have to rate limit the traffic on our end to prevent a denial of service attack. A resource intensive answer to Facebook's over active bot.

Comment: Holy moly what a mess! Such irrational denial from Facebook about the problem, how can they not accept this is devastatingly bad?!

Answer (score 8):

Sources say that Facebook/Externalhit does not respect crawl-delay in robots.txt because Facebook doesn't use a crawler, it uses a scraper.

Whenever one of your pages is shared on Facebook, it scrapes your site for your meta title, description and image.

My guess is that if Facebook is scraping your site 11,000 times in 15 minutes then I think the most likely scenario is that someone has figured out how to abuse the Facebook scraper to DDOS your site.

Perhaps they are running a bot that is clicking on your share link over and over, and Facebook is scraping your page every time that it does.

Off the top of my head, the first thing that I would try to do is cache the pages that Facebook is scraping. You can do this in htaccess. This will hopefully tell Facebook not to load your page with every share until the cache expires.

Because of your issue, I would set the html expiry to longer than usual

In .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c> 
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 60 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 900 seconds"

</IfModule>
```

Setting html to expire at 900 seconds will hopefully prevent Facebook from crawling any individual page at more than once per 15 minutes.

---

Edit:
I ran a quick search and found a page written a few years ago that discusses the very issue you're encountering now. This person discovered that websites could be flooded by the Facebook scraper through its share feature. He reported it to Facebook but they chose to do nothing about it. Perhaps the article will more clearly tell you what is happening to you and maybe it can lead you in the right direction as to how you'd like to deal with the situation:

http://chr13.com/2014/04/20/using-facebook-notes-to-ddos-any-website/

Comment: Good approach to the problem

Comment: It also occurred to me that if you do nothing about the issue and Facebook continues to flood your server, this could potentially be considered a DDOS attack in a court of law and you and your company could be monetarily compensated for the destruction of your business by Facebook servers.

Comment: We're using Cloudflare but many of these pages hit can't cache responses. They're for tickets and need to be 100% up to date. The 'scraper' is also going into our payment process - which is alarming. That's a clear no-no in our robots.txt. It also means it's creating sessions on our server!!!

Comment: I would read through the URL I included in my message, look for keywords in it and then search the web to see if anyone has come up with a solution to this problem other than blocking Facebook's IP altogether.

Comment: I don't think it's related to the news article about the vulnerability in FB Notes. That is specifically about including media files, which doesn't seem to be the problem here. The problem is FB spidering entire domains with no respect for robots.txt OR rel=nofollow. Our server is being overwhelmed with requests, many to useless old URLs no one would ever share.